# Mysql Error 1093

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a new record in a table `Points` using data queried from the very same table but I get the following error

> `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'Points' for update in FROM clause`

Here is query:

```
insert into Points (`userID`,`restaurantID`,`franchiseID`,`points`) 
values (16,5,1,((SELECT 
                       FORMAT(SUM(itemPrice)/10,0)  
                 FROM 
                    Orders left join Menu using(menuID) 
                 WHERE 
                    logID = 701)+
                (SELECT 
                    SUM(points) 
                 FROM 
                    Points 
                 WHERE `userID` = 16 AND `franchiseID`=1)))
```

I am not so skilled in MySQL so I was wondering if there was a workaround this problem I have. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it will work if you wrap the whole `((SELECT ... `franchiseID`=1))` thing in a subquery.

Comment: You could also store the result of the `select` in a variable and than insert this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the temporary result in a user variable:

```
SET @sum_val := (SELECT 
                       FORMAT(SUM(itemPrice)/10,0)  
                 FROM 
                    Orders left join Menu using(menuID) 
                 WHERE 
                    logID = 701)+
                (SELECT 
                    SUM(points) 
                 FROM 
                    Points 
                 WHERE `userID` = 16 AND `franchiseID`=1));
insert into Points (`userID`,`restaurantID`,`franchiseID`,`points`) 
values (16,5,1,@sum_val);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MySQL doesn't let you do that.  I set up a contrived example and got your same results:

```
create table blah (a bigint not null primary key auto_increment, b varchar(6));
insert into blah (b) values ('junk');

select * from blah;
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 1 | junk |
+---+------+

 insert into blah (b) values ((select b from blah where a = 1));
 ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'blah' for update in FROM clause
```

Sorry, buddy!  From the MySQL docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html):

> In MySQL, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. This applies to statements such as DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, UPDATE, and (because subqueries can be used in the SET clause) LOAD DATA INFILE.

Sasha Pachev's answer is a good suggestion, but Giorgos Betsos suggested an elegant workaround in a comment on this answer:

```
insert into blah (b) values ((select b from (select b from blah where a = 1) as t));

select * from blah;
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 1 | junk |
| 2 | junk |
+---+------+
```

By adding another layer of subquery with an alias, it looks like MySQL creates a temporary table under the covers, thereby working around the limitation.  (Unfortunately my installed version of MySQL will not EXPLAIN inserts, but EXPLAINing the nested subquery shows a derived table)

Comment: Yes, but there is a work-around: `insert into blah (b) values 
((select b from (select b from blah where a = 1) as t));`

Comment: Thanks for the info buddy

Comment: Good explanation! The real query is going to be a bit more complicated though because the OP is selecting *scalars*, something similar to: `insert into blah (b) values ((select b from (select ((select count(*) from blah) + 1) as b) as c))`